# What container is the best to manage XML data?

Tags: c++, containers

Imagine I have XML data:

```
<tag> value</tag> etc ....
<othertag> value  value2 value_n </othertag> 
etc ....
```

What is the best container to manage this informaction?
A simple vector, a list, other?

I'm going to do simple insertions, searchings, deletions.
Of course the code are going to be 'some rude'.

I know that there will be XML specific utilities, but I'd want to know your opinion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"The best container" to manage XML is usually a DOM tree, since it can store all the information stored in the XML source and present it in a code-friendly way; still, depending on what you want to do to this data, it can be overkill.

On the other hand, since what you want to do are actually generic manipulations of the XML tree, I think it could be your best option; grab a good XML parser that produces a DOM tree and use it.

---

A personal note: *please*, don't reinvent an XML square wheel yet another time - there are enough broken XML parsers around, we don't need yet another one. Use a well known, standard conforming XML parser (e.g. [Xerces-C++](http://xerces.apache.org/xerces-c/)) that produces your DOM tree and be happy with it.

Answer (score 1):

Well that highly depends on your xml data. Do have have a list of objects with no special identificators? Or do you want to be able to quickly ID an object in your list (i.e. have a mapping?).

You can always use http://linuxsoftware.co.nz/cppcontainers.html to make a decision. The flowchart at the bottom of the page is particularly useful.